# Retrieve the id of an Entity object as soon as the entity was instantiated?

Tags: jsf, jpa

Is there a way in JPA to retrieve the id of an Entity object as soon as the entity was instantiated? e.g `Person person = new Person();`

Currently i am using in my entity class the following strategy:
`@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

If not is there a "Dummy Id" strategy for having a dummyId e.g -10 etc  before the actual primary key is set by the table in the database? Please note that the primary key in MySQL DB is set as AutoIncrement.

The reason i need this is to be able to add new Entities in Lists and sort them using there id in JSF datatables before persisting them in to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to retrieve the ID before persisting - simply because it has no ID until you persist your entity. This has nothing to do with your strategy. It has something to do with concurrence.

But you can add your own temporary key for your use case:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private final transient long tempId = counter.decrementAndGet();

    public long getIdForComparison() {
        return id == null ? tempId : id;
    }

}
```

Remember that `counter` will decrease for every created object - even for those instantiated by the JPA provider. If you would like to count only new (unpersisted) objects, or are worried about the time of the atomic counter, you should use a different constructor for JPA:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    private static final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private transient long tempId;

    private String name;

    protected Person() {
        // Constructor for JPA - nothing to do, the id will get attached
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        // Constructor for creation of new objects
        tempId = counter.decrementAndGet();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getIdForComparison() {
        return id == null ? tempId : id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Tobias thanks for the response, i had something similar in mind, i just wanted to check if there was something readymade from jpa implmentations!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way without persisting it in the DB right away, but that's clearly not what you want, after all. Provided that there's only one "new" person at once, you could just manually set the "dummy id".

```
person.setId(0L);
```

Don't forget to clear out it before persist.

```
person.setId(null);
// ...
em.persist(person);
```

Comment: In case that Field-based access is used (the more common case), then I would suggest to create not setter for id, because `getId() != null` will be a cheap indicator that the entity is persistent. And I think that the ID should be immutable nevertheless.